# How to manipulate a non-DOM jQuery object

Tags: html, jquery

I have a text string with HTML embedded in it. It also has CRs and/or newlines as well as tabs. I convert it into a jQuery object by passing it to to jQuery:

```
var htmlJqueryObj = jQuery(mystring);
```

Now I want to select and manipulate stuff within it via jQuery:

```
var modJqueryObj = jQuery("#"+buttonsParentID,htmlJqueryObj).clone().insertAfter(jQuery("#"+buttonsParentID,htmlJqueryObj));
```

however the above just returns a clone of the selected elements, while I would like it to insert a clone of the selected elements after those elements and return the the original jQuery object with the modified content.

Ideas?

Comment: Just a quick thought... how about adding the string as html into an invisible div, and then using jQuery to traverse/select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery `end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) ftw:

```
var modJqueryObj =
    jQuery("#"+buttonsParentID,htmlJqueryObj)
        .clone()
             .insertAfter(jQuery("#"+buttonsParentID,htmlJqueryObj))
        .end()
    .end();
```